# Can we work on overview questions together? Expressions of interest open now

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

The idea of Overview Questions on site idea sounds really good: get an overview of all the major Christian denominations on one particular question, in one place, each view explaining its perspective fairly and neutrally. In practice though, overview questions are *really hard* to answer properly. People have raised the idea of working on collaborating to answer overview questions before, which sounds good, but no concrete plan was worked out. So I'd like to raise the following as a possible way forward.

1. People sign up to represent their denomination in the project. It's fine for more than one person from each to join up, and people can join or leave at any time. If more than one person signs up for a position then they can either work together or take turns, as they decide for themselves.
2. We make a chat room for discussing and planning the project.
3. We have a meta question for nominating overview questions to handle, and then vote to select one at a regular cadence, perhaps one per fortnight or month. (If votes are tied the chat room can just pick one.) It might be possible to use the events feature to advertise each one too.
4. We then make a wiki answer, and over the fortnight each perspective can fill in their position's answer. A typical response would be up to 250 words per position. Depending on the question some positions can work together (for example on some questions all Protestants might work together, or even all Trinitarians.)

What do you think about a project like this? Would you be interested in participating? Any part of this that you'd change?

Comment: This sound like you have a solid footing here!

Comment: It almost feels like this is asking to be a collection of tables/charts, grouped by topic. Maybe something like [this denomination chart on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/religion/comments/5dgzmp/christian_denominations_views_on_justification/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good idea, we'd have to have some sort of bat-signal.  But if you subscribe to the [overview-questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overview-questions) I'd imagine you'd at least have a fighting chance of getting an answer.

Sounds pretty much like what we used to do on the Eschewmenical blog BTW, and I'd be totally in for it!

Comment: Yeah I think the blog had basically wound up by the time I joined the site. If you remember how it was organised please share any tips!

Comment: We had a meta post with topics, took the highest rated topic and organized on google docs.  I think we can probably manage the organization in Chat for this though.  Waxeagle was in charge of the blog and he wanted to make sure we didn't write anything too crazy.  I don't think we'd need that kind of oversight on a Community Wiki since we can all edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd be interested in potentially interested, please add your name here (feel free to put yourself down more than one, for any group you would be able to help with. And feel free to add any branches I've missed.):

- Catholicism: Ken Graham, Matt Gutting

  - Eastern Catholicism: Ken Graham
- Eastern Orthodox: Ken Graham
- Oriental Orthodox: Ken Graham
- Protestantism: curiousdannii

  - Lutheran:
  - Reformed: curiousdannii

    - Presbyterian: curiousdannii
    - Continental reformed:
    - Reformed Baptist: curiousdannii
  - Anglican: curiousdannii
  - Arminian:

    - Methodism:
    - General Baptist:
  - Adventist:
  - Pentecostal:
- LDS:
- JW:
- Biblical Unitarian:
- Religious Society of Friends (Quakers)